# Searching for text in all nodes with xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to find words in a fragment of html to replace them with a href. Somehow can't find the right path to use for Xpath. Example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<p>A paragraph Apple<p>
<span>Apple</span>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Apple <strong>Apple</strong></li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
<p><i>Apple</i>Apple</p>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
doc.xpath('.//*[text()="Apple"]').each do |node|
  puts "\n"
  puts node.name
  puts node.content
  puts node.replace('REPLACED')
end

puts doc.to_html
```

**Result**:

```
span
Apple
REPLACED

strong
Apple
REPLACED

li
Apple
REPLACED

i
Apple
REPLACED
<p>A paragraph Apple</p><p>
REPLACED

</p><ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Apple REPLACED</li>
  REPLACED
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
<p>REPLACEDApple</p>
```

So the words in the root p elements are not replaced and one in the li is left. Which path should i use in this case to search in root and all children? Reading on a page like [this](https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/?s=chap_2.html) .//* should be the path used to search in root and child nodes. Any ideas on how to handle this correctly with nokogiri or xpath?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your desired results example isn't consistent with what you're saying you want or with the selected answer. Those details are really important when asking. Also, your input HTML isn't valid and Nokogiri will have to do fixups, changing it. `doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Tag apple invalid>]`

Comment: @theTinMan the apple tag is coming from html in the selected answer which Eric added as an example. I'm not sure why you think my result example is not consistent? What do you mean by that? I'm starting the question with what i want to achieve and show what i've got so far.. Not sure whats wrong with that tbh, but if i can improve the question i will.

Comment: You show `<span>` and `<i>` tags in the input that disappeared in the output. Do you want the tags removed? Your accepted answer doesn't match your required output, so, for consistency, and to avoid confusion of those looking for a similar solution in the future, you should reconcile the differences.  Currently there's a disconnect. SO isn't a "give me an answer" site, it's a reference site where your question and answers provide a solution to the problem for future searchers so making it all consistent helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for nodes where the whole text is equal to `"Apple"`, not nodes which contain `"Apple"`

```
html = '
<p>A paragraph Apple<p>
<span>Apple</span>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Apple <strong>Apple</strong></li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
<p><i>Apple</i>Apple</p>
<Apple>Dont replace!</Apple>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)

doc.traverse do |node|
  if node.text?
    node.content = node.content.gsub('Apple', 'REPLACED')
  end
end

puts doc.to_html
```

It outputs :

```
<p>A paragraph REPLACED</p><p>
<span>REPLACED</span>
</p><ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>REPLACED <strong>REPLACED</strong>
</li>
  <li>REPLACED</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
<p><i>REPLACED</i>REPLACED</p>
<apple>Dont replace!</apple>
```